# Is it possible to import class file without converting it to a dll in c#?

Tags: c#, class

There are a lot of variables and methods in my program and I want to seperate some of them in other class files. But as the program grows the methods and functions can change.

I searched on the net but many people generally speaking for dll files. Without making a dll file, how can I arrange my code and split into small class files?

Comment: Simply split it to namespaces

Comment: if you add a Class file to your project it will still be in the executable, not a different dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just split it out in to a separate file in a new class but still inside the same project. The term for what you are doing is called [Code Refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring). There are some tools [built in to Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/719exd8s.aspx) to make it easier to do, and there are some [3rd party tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) that add even more features to make it easier to do.

But all it boils down to is just making new classes in the same project and referencing those new classes from where you took the code out from.

Comment: Scott you have cathed the point. Let's say I moved  calculate() method to myExtraClass. In my main class, is it enough to calculate() or must I call everytime myExtraClass.calculate(). And finally adding a class as reference does the namespace jobs itself?

Comment: You would need to call `myExtraClass.calculate()`, however some of the tools I listed will automatically replace every refrence to `calculate()` to `myExtraClass.calculate()` for you and generate the new class and file all at the same time, that's why I said there are tools to make it easier to do. When I said add a class as a reference I meant adding  a `private MyExtraClass myExtraClass;` in your class and a `myExtraClass = new myExtraClass()` in the constructor (or it could be a static class, it all depends on if you need the class to preserve state).

Comment: Very kind and helpful. Thank you for your answers and links. I will go on from here.

Answer (score 1):

You can add folders to your solution. Classes are by default a namespaceprovider, so that classes in this folder have a different namespace.

For example if your default-namespace is *MyNameSpace* and you create a folder called Entity then all classes in this folder have the namespace *MyNameSpace.Entity*

And all Items in a project are compiled to one single dll or exe

Answer (score 1):

Just add more classes to the project and put the data and behavior (methods) into the appropriate classes. The project will still build into a single exe or dll.

Generally, it's better to add a second project under the same solution call it "CommonLib" or something like that. Then you add it as a reference to the main application and set up the project so that the applications build depends on the libraries build. Add a using statement for the common lib where ever you want to use those objects. This is definitely better for large scale or enterprise applications. There's a pretty decent chance that somewhere down the line you'll want to reuse some of this code, if everything builds into a single exe that won't be an option.